# bootstrap-select-rails not working with bootstrap 4

Tags: ruby, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am setting up a new project with Bootstrap 4 and the bootstrap-select-rails selectpicker. The selectpicker doesn't work and can't resolve the correct styling. This is what the selectpickers should look like: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/

Instead it servers the unstyled version like it would without the selectpicker gem included. Like in section 1 of the following page:

https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/useful-bootstrap-4-select-picker-for-your-forms/

I think I correctly installed all the necessary dependencies (popper.js, jquery, etc.)

I tried to use multiple versions of the bootstrap-select-rails gem and tried to include the selectpicker via the two suggested methods:

Via js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

And via adding the selectpicker class to the formfield

```
<%= f.input :use_standard_steps, label: 'Select input test', as: :select, collection: ['a','b','c'], required: false, input_html: { class: "selectpicker", multiple: true } %>
```

Below is a copy of my gemfile:

```
ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'
gem 'bootstrap-select-rails', '~> 1.3.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap4-datetime-picker-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.6.2'
gem 'factory_bot_rails'
gem 'faker', '1.9.1' # Create fake database data
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.6.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 6.0.1'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.20.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1.4'
gem 'popper_js', '~> 1.14.5'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 4.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.x'
```

A copy of my application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require moment
//= require moment/nl.js
//= require tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap-select
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And a copy of my application.css.scss

```
@import "jquery-ui";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap-select';
@import "tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css";
@import "custom";
@import "general";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,600,700,800');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
```

Chrome Inspect shows that the Bootstrap-selectpicker css is included in my HEAD

Can someone point out the flaws in my setup?

Comment: Try moving jquery and jquery-ui before bootstrap in you applications.js file.

Comment: @hashrocket, thanks, I tried, but it makes no difference unfortunately. Also did the same for application.css.sccs. Same result

Comment: Instead of $(document).ready, try $(document).on(‘turbolinks:load’, function() {})

Comment: Hey man, thanks! This seems to partly solve the problem. The given form is rendered via turbolinks. When I call $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); from this js file the dropdown is loaded. It doesn's however change the styling. https://i.imgur.com/OL987a9.png 

I tried to swap around the items in my application.css.scss, but this doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: According to the docs for bootstrap-select-rails: Also, you must require at least the alert and dropdown bootstrap components. For example, if using bootstrap-sass: //= require bootstrap/alert, //= require bootstrap/dropdown. I don't see either one of these in your application.js

Comment: I added both lines earlier, but it didn't make a difference unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though. I've put them back in the application.js for now and updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve the problem via the bootstrap-select-rails or changing the order of my application.js and application.scss. I included the latest version of both the css and js file in my assets instead.This solved the problem for me.